# CSS - How to get variable width <LI> in my Vertical Nav Menu <UL>

Tags: html, css, menu, menuitem

I have a **vertical** navigation menu `<UL>` with every `<LI>` as long as the widest element.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1satJ.png

How can I use CSS to resize each `<LI>` to only be as wide as necessary, while maintaining the **vertical** orientation?

I've tried `.main-navigation li {display: inline-block;}`and `.main-navigation li {float: left;}`but they both turned my menu horizontal which I don't want.

My `<UL>` is called`.main-navigation ul` if that helps.
Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Better apply styles to the elements inside the LI, not the LI itself.

```css
.main-navigation ul{
  list-style: none
}

.main-navigation li{
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center
}

.main-navigation a{
  text-decoration: none;
  display:inline
}

.main-navigation a:hover{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f00
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<div class="main-navigation">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Long Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Even longer Navigation Link</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```